# Dangerous query string, yet it has not changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, query-string, code-behind

Running into an issue with a simple change to some code - error is stating the query string may be dangerous. The query string has remained the same, all I have changed is the code behind for the modal the query string calls

code before change (works):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Check();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Bunch of methods
        }

        Set();
    }
```

after (not working):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Check();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (UserInfo.Promotion != string.Empty && Request.QueryString["modal"].ToString() == "changeplan")
            {
                SetPageContentWithPromotion();
            }
            else
            {
                //Bunch of method
            }
        }

        Set();
    }
}

private void SetPageContentWithPromotion()
    {
        //bunch of logic to set up page
    }
```

I set break points and they are not even hit. The page just displays an error and the code behind for the modal is never touched. I am stumped

Comment: _the page just displays an error_ care to share?

Comment: @Steve A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client. Which I find odd, as I have only made a change to the logic in the page_load event of the modal's code behind

Comment: In debug, could you see what the dangerous value was? Since you did not post the complete code, its hard to imageine what could be dangrous..

Comment: Please show us the whole error message, not just a few words you picked out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line to your web.config if it's not there:

> ```
>  <system.web>
>    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
>  </system.web>
> ```

then on that particular aspx page set this property in your page tag like below:

> ```
> <%@ Page ValidateRequest="false"
> ```

however this is against your page's security.